# 2 DrawerNavigators on page

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-drawer

I created two basic DrawerNavigators. One is for the left side, and the other is for the right side of the top bar:

```
const LeftDrawer = DrawerNavigator({

    MenuScreen: { screen: MenuScreen }
}, getDrawerConfig(300, 'left', 'MainScreen'));


export default LeftDrawer;


const RightDrawer = DrawerNavigator({

    AccountScreen: { screen: AccountScreen }
}, getDrawerConfig(300, 'right', 'MainScreen'));


export default RightDrawer;
```

Is it possible to use both drawers inside the MainScreen view?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using one DrawerNavigator as the main navigator and nesting the other DrawerNavigator inside the first one should do.

```
const MainDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
    OtherDrawer: DrawerNavigator({
        AccountScreen: { screen: AccountScreen }
    }, getDrawerConfig(300, 'right', 'MainScreen')),
    MenuScreen: { screen: MenuScreen }
}, getDrawerConfig(300, 'left', 'MainScreen'));

export default MainDrawer;
```